# Mask-Money não funciona em input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho um formulário com campos em array

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="item" name="item[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->item }}"></td>
    <td><input id="descricao" name="descricao[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->descricao }}"></td>
    <td><input id="quantidade" name="quantidade[]" type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->quantidade }}"></td>
    <td><input id="valor_unitario" name="valor_unitario[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->valor_unitario }}"></td>
    <td><input id="desconto" name="desconto[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->desconto }}"></td>
    <td><input id="total" name="total[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->quantidade * $servico->valor_unitario - $servico->desconto }}" readonly></td>
    <td><a onclick="RemoveTableRowOrcamento(this)" id="delete" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

e esse script

```
$(function() {
    $("#valor_unitario").maskMoney();
    $("#desconto").maskMoney();
});
```

porém só funciona a mask nos dois primeiros input.. valor_unitario e desconto, depois não funciona mas nos próximos do array.

Comment: Caro Micheal, IDs não podem se repetir, a cada TR vc provavelmente esta repetindo IDs

Comment: Michael, caso já tenha conseguido a resposta, encerre essa pergunta informando qual a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O id é um identificador único, logo só vai ser inserido na primeira tag que o mesmo foi encontrado, tente utilizar uma classe como da seguinte maneira:

```
<tr>
   <td><input id="item" name="item[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->item }}"></td>
   <td><input id="descricao" name="descricao[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->descricao }}"></td>
   <td><input id="quantidade" name="quantidade[]" type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->quantidade }}"></td>
   <td><input id="valor_unitario" name="valor_unitario[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm valor-unitario" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->valor_unitario }}"></td>
   <td><input id="desconto" name="desconto[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm desconto" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->desconto }}"></td>
   <td><input id="total" name="total[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ $servico->quantidade * $servico->valor_unitario - $servico->desconto }}" readonly></td>
   <td><a onclick="RemoveTableRowOrcamento(this)" id="delete" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

E o script:

```
$(function() {
   $(".valor-unitario").maskMoney();
   $(".desconto").maskMoney();
});
```

Comment: exatamente isso mano vlw! você é o cara o//

Answer (score 0):

Não há erro de sintaxe no seu código, ele irá adicionar as mask nos IDs encontrados nos inputs, no caso os que foram definidos por você: `#valor_unitario` e 
 `#desconto`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#valor_unitario").maskMoney();
  $("#desconto").maskMoney();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<input id="desconto" name="desconto[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
<br/>
<input id="valor_unitario" name="valor_unitario[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
```